# ascending or descending with respect to multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sorting, join

I have two tables

**medicine:**

```
id | name
---------
1  | Aspirin
2  | Panadol
3  | Dicloran
```

**pricing:**

```
medicine_id | Strength | DosageForm |PackSize | Price|
---------
1           | 20mg     | tablet     |14's     | 2    |
1           | 40mg     | tablet     |14's     | 4    |
1           | 60mg     | tablet     |14's     | 6    |
2           | 10mg     | tablet     |20's     | 5    |
3           | 60mg     | tablet     |14's     | 6    |
3           | 2     cc | injection  |1        | 6    |
```

Each medicines have different packs and pricing.

I want help in  MySql Query in which i can get medicines with respect to pricing descending to ascending in which `medicine_id` is FK and `id` in medicine is PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to return a query with all the information, and sort by price?

If so, try this

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.name,
       p.strength,
       p.dosageform,
       p.packsize,
       p.price
FROM medicine m
INNER JOIN pricing p ON m.id = p.medicine_id
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```